# django-cms cannot edit/add plugins to a page

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-cms

I've a django project on heroku and amazon s3. I'm using django 1.4.2 and django-cms 2.3.4
My problem is that i can't edit or add any plugins to pages.
Yesterday it works perfect but after I have changed a few things in a textfield it all went wrong...
The problem with the textfield is fixed now but i still can't edit/add any plugins. the only things I know are the following error-messages:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Uncaught ReferenceError: cms_plugin_editor_jQuery is not defined xy.herokuapp.com:396
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined change_form.js:48
```

can anyone help me please?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Spend 2 hours trying to solve it the sane way. Haven`t found the answer.
I was at app rev 33. I have reverted to 32 version at heroku website. It worked there. Reverted back to 33 and it also worked.

Maybe it has something to do with heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you are not running into an issue with CSRF middleware not being loaded.  The CMS expects it in the admin and will generate this error when it is not available.